# Audio Equipment in FAQ permissible list

Tags: discussion, support

Hi,

I was wondering if 'audio equipments' are deliberately excluded from permissible topics list in the audio.stackexchange.com FAQ page, as I have not found any implicit or explicit references to the same.

It would be nice if someone throws more light on question policy for audio-equipments.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. Can you give us an example of a question about "audio equipments"?

Comment: My purpose of asking this was what kind/range of audio equipments questions are permissible here. As, a pro mixer or amplifier is an 'equipment' so is a simple over-the-counter guitar. Some might argue guitar is a musical instrument and there fore not exactly valid here but so are some synthesizers and entry-mid level keyboards, but they kind of seem to fit in here.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your comment into the body of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Questions about equipment directly related to recording are on topic (e.g. microphones, mixing desks, headphones) etc.

My feeling about questions on musical instruments is that they are on topic so long as they relate to getting a good sound for recording or live sound purposes. There is [music.stackexchange.com](http://music.stackexchange.com) if you need to ask questions relating to learning to play the instrument.

Having a quick look at the [questions already asked here on guitar](http://audio.stackexchange.com/search?q=guitar) reveals that most people are getting this right anyway.

Comment: This answer echoes my own opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Questions about how to use your equipment and how to make the most of it are fine. You can even talk about what type of features you should look for to solve a specific problem. But keep in mind that asking for specific shopping recommendations are not generally appropriate for this type of Q&A.

[**Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 1):

Very good point.  I believe you are referring to questions like those tagged [hardware](http://audio.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware).  I believe the consensus from [this discussion](http://meta.audio.stackexchange.com/questions/96/are-equipment-repair-questions-on-topic) was that these questions are on topic.  I'll discuss with the other mods on working this into the FAQ.